# Having Issues Importing and Using RLGlue locally with Python For Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I'm going through an online course on Coursera for Reinforcement Learning that makes use of RLGlue. I want to try to run and adapt the code locally, but am having issues using RLGlue, and not sure why.

I was going through an Reinforcement Learning Course and wanted to try running the code locally. I installed RLGlue with `pip install rlglue` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/rlglue/)

But then when trying to run the code:

```
from rlglue.rl_glue import RLGlue
import main_agent
import ten_arm_env
import test_env
```

Received this error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rlglue.rl_glue'`

I also attempted to install it from [here](https://github.com/andnp/coursera-rl-glue) that supports the course, and with
`pip install git+https://github.com/andnp/coursera-rl-glue.git@0.1`
but that didn't work either.

Any idea on how to fix that to import the module and run the code?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
from RLGlue.rl_glue import RLGlue
This is only with the Coursera version of RLGlue